# Add phone call only MFA to custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an existing custom policy (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/) and I want to add phone MFA to this.
I found https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone but this allows email or phone, there is also https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-auth-technical-profile.

Is there any way to force a phone call as mfa? (don't allow sms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this [setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-factor-technical-profile#metadata):

```
"setting.authenticationMode"
```

"The method to validate the phone number. Possible values: sms, phone, or mixed (default)"

Comment: Thank you! Now I am just struggling getting the profile in. They reference this `<TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">` but I get the error that it does not exist. I also tried `<TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-Common">` which is used in the user flow. I searched the web for both technical profiles, but can't find them.

Comment: They are in the sample you referenced - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone/policy/SignUpOrSignin.xml

Comment: It's referencing it but not defining it and thus fails for me. ```<ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PhoneFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify"/>
          </ClaimsExchanges>```

Comment: Copy them from the sample to your policy.